# ListlogLogPlot can't work on y axis

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have a table:

```
lengthvstemp={
  {3.15449,1.46395*10^-7}, 
  {0.623364,1.35011*10^-7},
  {0.250102,1.22539*10^-7},
  {0.124968, 9.6637*10^-8}, 
  {0.100013,.47764*10^-8}
 };
```

When I make `ListLogLogPlot`:

```
ListLogLogPlot[lengthvstemp]
```

It gives me a plot like this:

[image]

Apparently the y axis is not on log scale. Has any one had the same issue or known what's going on?

Comment: John, the plot you showed is not what I obtain when trying to plot your data. Try adding `PlotRange -> All` to your plot and see if that improves your situation.

Comment: yeah, that's an good idea, but not working for me. Maybe it's because of the version problem as Verbeia♦ said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually *is* a log scale on the vertical axis, if you look carefully. The major tick marks get a little closer together as the values increase, but it is a subtle difference.

However your data set seems to have tripped some differences in the way version 10 handles automatic plot ranges and tickmarks, relative to version 9.

This is what I get in version 10.1.

[image]

Here is the same data and commands in version 9.0.1

[image]

Both are from fresh sessions. For reasons I don't yet understand, my two Mathematicas are interpreting `PlotRange -> Automatic` as `PlotRange -> Full`, but yours isn't.

Comment: Thanks. This looks good. But I have tried PlotRange -> Automatic / All / Full , and they all give the same result. I have Mathematica version 10.0, I am trying to update it to 10.1.

Comment: That is strange. Are you sure your data is what you posted here?

Comment: I found something interesting. The graph I posted in the question is the plotting in a ".m" package. I just evaluated it in notebook, it gives me the same result as you posted for version 10.1. So if I work in a package  it still can't plot it right. Any idea?

Comment: @Johneyishere Both in version 8.0.4 and 10.1 (under Win7) your code works correctly for me even if I import it from a package.

Comment: So problem solved. In the package evaluation to get the desired result, I have to specify the plot range on y axis.